# For a binary array sum(array) and numpy.count_nonzero(array) give different answers for big arrays, when array is uint8. Why?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sum

I have 3D arrays filled with ones and zeros (created through pyellipsoid). The array is uint8. I wanted to know the number of 1s. I used sum(sum(sum(array))) to do this and it worked fine for small arrays (up to approx.5000 entries).

I compared sum(sum(sum(array))) to numpy.count_nonzero(array) for a known number of nonzero entries. For bigger arrays the answers from "sum" are always wrong and lower than they should be.

If I use float64 arrays it works fine with big arrays. If I change the data type to uint8 it does not work.

Why is that? I am sure there is a very simple reason, but I can't find an answer.

Small array example:

```
test = numpy.zeros((2,2,2))
test[0,0,0] = 1  
test[1,0,0] = 1
In: test
Out: 
array([[[1., 0.],
        [0., 0.]],
In: sum(sum(sum(test)))
Out: 2.0
```

Big example (8000 entries, only one zero, 7999 ones):

```
test_big=np.ones((20,20,20))
test_big[0,0,0] = 0
test_big
Out[77]: 
array([[[0., 1., 1., ..., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1., ..., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1., ..., 1., 1., 1.],
        ...,
        [1., 1., 1., ..., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1., ..., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1., ..., 1., 1., 1.]],

       [[1., 1., 1., ..., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1., ..., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1., ..., 1., 1., 1.],
        ...,
        [1., 1., 1., ..., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1., ..., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1., ..., 1., 1., 1.]],

       [[1., 1., 1., ..., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1., ..., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1., ..., 1., 1., 1.],
        ...,
        [1., 1., 1., ..., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1., ..., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1., ..., 1., 1., 1.]],

       ...,

       [[1., 1., 1., ..., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1., ..., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1., ..., 1., 1., 1.],
        ...,
        [1., 1., 1., ..., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1., ..., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1., ..., 1., 1., 1.]],

       [[1., 1., 1., ..., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1., ..., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1., ..., 1., 1., 1.],
        ...,
        [1., 1., 1., ..., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1., ..., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1., ..., 1., 1., 1.]],

       [[1., 1., 1., ..., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1., ..., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1., ..., 1., 1., 1.],
        ...,
        [1., 1., 1., ..., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1., ..., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1., ..., 1., 1., 1.]]])
In: sum(sum(sum(test_big)))
Out: 7999.0
```

So far so good. Here, the data type of the sum output is float64.  But if I now change the data type of the array to the type that is used with pyellipsoid (uint8)...

```
In: test_big = test_big.astype('uint8')
In: sum(sum(sum(test_big)))
Out: 2879
```

So obviously 2879 is not 7999. Here, the data type of the sum output is int32  (-2147483648 to 2147483647) so this should be big enough for 7999, right? I guess it has something to do with the data type, but how? Why?

(I am using Spyder in Anaconda on Windows).

Comment: You have an [int overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow) when using Python  `sum`. Just use `numpy`: `test_big.sum()`

Comment: Try `numpy.sum` instead.

Comment: It looks like you have an integer overflow. Maybe you could use `np.sum` instead of `sum`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is as you guessed - there is an integer overflow. If you take a look at `sum(sum(test_big))`, you will notice that the values are wrong there.

The part that is wrong is that integer overflow can occur in your `sum()` functions which are taking the partial sums.

What I would suggest is making a sum of this array using `np.sum()` as it does give an appropriate sum despite of data type.

Comment: Great thanks, I double checked and indeed in the example the issue occurs at the second sum, giving 144 instead of 400 as partial sums (400-256=144):
>>> In: sum((sum(test_big)))
>>> Out: 
>>> array([143, 144, 144, 144, 144, 144, 144, 144, 144, 144, 144, 144, 144,
       144, 144, 144, 144, 144, 144, 144], dtype=uint8)   
Thanks, np.sum() works well!